# Visual Studio 11 BETA and Windows Phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7, visual-studio-2012

Is there a way to get windows phone 7 to work with VS 11 Beta?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They have a fix now.  See...

http://windowsteamblog.com/windows_phone/b/wpdev/archive/2012/03/26/wpsdk-711-now-available.aspx

and

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29233

Looks like the best interim solution for WP7 dev on Windows 8.

Answer (score 5):

This is not currently supported.

VS11 is currently in Beta to enable testing and familiarity with the new version. It exists to enable you in "preparing for the next generation of development". It is not intended to be used as a primary development environment for older technologies.

**Update**
Microsoft have confirmed this at http://windowsteamblog.com/windows_phone/b/wpdev/archive/2012/03/05/windows-8-and-the-windows-phone-sdk.aspx

Comment: i would disagree a little with that. Its hard to fully evaluate the beta when you have solutions that have many project types, including windows phone, in them. Especially since this is the only beta that will be released. Perhaps they will release an sdk update with support prior to release, like they plan to do with Azure.

Comment: @ChrisKirby no related SDK has been announced and the quote in my answer is from MSDN on the VS11 Beta announcement page. They've said that the purpose of the beta is to allow develoeprs to prepare for developing with and for the "next generation" of technologies. The beta was not released to enable testing with current technologies.  Yes, support for development for a version of Windows Phone will be necessary but it wouldn't be unprecedented if VS11 only included support for the next version of Windows Phone and development for Windows Phone 7 was only supported in VS2010.

Comment: It does make sense. Thankfully both vs10 & vs11 can co-exist quite well together. They've done a nice job of project and solution compatibility between the two as well.